# Removal extra column from a dataframe after full_join function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm currently involved in Data Manipulation Task in R and trying to combine two datasets on chosen columns (= using primary and foreign keys - Column2)

```
Column1 <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4")
Column2 <- c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4")
Column3 <- c(4, 5, 6, 7)
Column4 <- c(8, 9, 10, 11)
Column5 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

table1 <- data.frame(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
```

```
Column1 <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4")
Column2 <- c("ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7")
Column3 <- c(22, 33, 44, 66)
Column4 <- c(66, 55, 77, 77)
Column5 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

table2 <- data.frame(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
```

```
table3 <- full_join(table1, table2, by = "Column2")
```

I've opted for a full join function as it may help to solve my task but encountered with a problem: using full_join function R shows the Column1.y column from the second table instead of listing the values of this column down to Column.1.x

For example, R produces: Column.1.x then Column2, Column3.x, Column4.x, Column5.x, next to the Column5.x I want to display Columns "Column3.y", "Column4.y", "Column5.y", but "Column.1.y" is displayed right after Column5.x instead of to be displayed down to "Column.1.x" where all the names are listed.

How can I fix it? :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get adequate support please provide a minimal reproducible exmaple <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>. I guess you need another join (maybe inner_join or left_join).

Comment: Without a reprex it's tough to answer, but can you just not add a step to unselect your Column.1.y?  something like:  full_join(x,y) %>% select(-Column1.y)

Comment: DarwinsBeard, thank you for the help! The code listed by you really deletes the entire column "Column1.y", but it is also vital to display the values of this column down to the values of "Column1.x"..

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I go with @DarwinsBeard, you can "remove" the unwanted column, Column1.y.
Keep in mind that you can perform joins with more than 1 key. That is the reason why you get Column1.x and Column1.y as this is not a join key and appears in both tables.

Check the following:

```
df1 <- tibble( Column1 = c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4")
              ,Column2 = c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4")
              # I save Column3 and Column4 
              ,Column5 = c(1,2,3,4)
              )
df2 <- tibble( Column1 = c("Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7")
              ,Column2 = c("ID4","ID5","ID6","ID7")
              ,Yes     = c(8,5,6,7) 
              ,No      = c(13,10,11,12)
              ,Neither = NA
              )

# full join keeps columns of both data frames, but replicates Column1
# as the join was only performed on the id-column, i.e. Column2
# as suggested above, remove the unwanted Column1.y with a select(-...) call
df12 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("Column2"))
df12

# what I think you want
df12 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("Column1","Column2"))
df12
```

The latter gives you a fully merged data set by keeping both key columns intact.

[image]

Note: You can reshuffle the sequence of columns to your liking with a select() call. E.g. try: `df12 %>% select(Yes, No, Either, everything())` to see what happens.

Comment: Happy to see that you can move on. I also appreciate that you took the effort to move from the initial pictures of your problem to some code to recreate your problem data. That is close to a reprex and will make you a lot of friends here. Good luck with your further journey!

Answer (score 0):

```
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2,by = c("Column1" = "Column1"))
df3
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2.x Column5 Column2.y   Yes    No Neither
  <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
1 Name1   ID1             1 NA           NA    NA NA     
2 Name2   ID2             2 NA           NA    NA NA     
3 Name3   ID3             3 NA           NA    NA NA     
4 Name4   ID4             4 ID4           8    13 NA     
5 Name5   NA             NA ID5           5    10 NA     
6 Name6   NA             NA ID6           6    11 NA     
7 Name7   NA             NA ID7           7    12 NA
```